# How do I ensure the generated query for detecting Azure B2C signin failures works?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-insights, kql, azureportal

When selecting my B2C tenant, the Azure Portal shows the following message:

"Looking for Log Analytics? In Log Analytics you can search for performance, diagnostics, health logs, and more. Visit Log Analytics"

So I click " Visit Log Analytics"

[image]

and then "Failed Signin reasons" (Run).
[image]

The shown query is generated and its table and [known to exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/signinlogs)

but still the table name can't be resolved.... How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

> The error usually occurs if you **missed** integrating Azure AD B2C with Azure Monitor before running KQL query.

Initially, I ran that query without configuring `Diagnostic settings` for my B2C tenant and got **same error** as below:

```
SigninLogs
| where ResultType != 0
| summarize Count=count() by ResultDescription, ResultType
| sort by Count desc nulls last
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to set up monitoring for your B2C tenant before running KQL queries.

In my case, I followed this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor) and configured monitoring by adding **Diagnostic setting** for my B2C tenant like this:

[image]

When I ran same **KQL query** after some time in configured Log Analytics workspace, I got the  results successfully as below:

```
SigninLogs
| where ResultType != 0
| summarize Count=count() by ResultDescription, ResultType
| sort by Count desc nulls last
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Monitor Azure AD B2C with Azure Monitor - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor)